# Bind object in attr binding - KnockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Have a requirement where in I need to bind object in the value attribute, because KnockoutJs send value as first parameter in checkbox event.
When passed as single value, things are fine.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Items">
   <input type="checkbox" value data-bind="attr: { value: id }, checked: selectedVal">

this.selectedVal.subscribe((newVal: any) => {
  alert(newVal);
});
```

I want to pass the iterated item object itself, rather than one property of the iterated item.

```
Items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Adam',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bailey',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Cathy',
  },
]
```

On subscribe I want entire object with id and name, let me know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `checkedValue: $data` to tell the checkbox to write the whole object. For example:

```js
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Adam',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Bailey',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Cathy',
  },
];

const selected = ko.observableArray([]);

selected.subscribe(console.log);

ko.applyBindings({ items, selected });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
  <label>
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: selected">
   <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </label> 
</div>
```